# FancyBox - проблема с отображением изображения в Edge и IE11

Tags: asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer, fancybox, microsoft-edge

**HTML разметка**

```
<a class="fancybox" rel="fncbx" href="data:image/jpeg;base64,@Convert.ToBase64String(item.Image)" target="_blank">
    <img src="data:image;base64,@Convert.ToBase64String(item.Image)" class="img-thumbnail" alt="Cinque Terre" width="374" height="278">
</a>
```

**Javascript**

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>    
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("a.fancybox").fancybox({
            openEffect: 'elastic',
            closeEffect: 'elastic',
            zoomSpeedIn: 300,
            zoomSpeedOut: 300,
            overlayShow: false
        });
    });
</script>
```

*Результат в Opera, Opera Neon, Chrome:*
[image: Изображение при нажатие на a.fancybox в Opera Neon]

*Результат в Edge, IE:*
[image: Изображение при нажатие на a.fancybox в Edge]

**Как решить эту проблему отображения в Edge i IE?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проводя поиск в интернете и тестируя различные попытки исправить отображение изображений стало явным, что **в Edge i IE не поддерживается Data URI link**`<a href="data:...`
Но есть поддержка Data Uri тега `<img>`.

Поэтому решением есть **брать атрибут href у `<img src="...">` через Javascript**.

***Изменение разметки***

```
    <a class="fancybox" rel="fncbx" href="#" target="_blank">
       <img src="data:image;base64,@Convert.ToBase64String(item.Image)" class="img-thumbnail" alt="Cinque Terre" width="374" height="278">
    </a>
```

***Изменение скрипта для инициализации FancyBox***

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("a.fancybox").each(function (i, elem) {
            var href = $(this).find('img').attr('src');
            if (href !== undefined) {
                $(this).fancybox({
                    href: href,
                    type: 'image',
                    openEffect: 'elastic',
                    closeEffect: 'elastic',
                    zoomSpeedIn: 300,
                    zoomSpeedOut: 300,
                    overlayShow: false,
                });
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
```

В результате изображение теперь отображается как и задумывалось. 
***Результат:***
[image: Работающее отображение изображения в Edge]

Правда в Edge и IE есть задержки отображения - но главное, что работает